# My code always returns true, even when it should be false

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, contains

I was wondering if I could get some help making this work propery.

```
    DevCon = File.ReadAllText("DevConDump.txt")
    DevID = File.ReadAllText("isLegacy.txt")
    DevCon = DevCon.ToUpper
    DevID = DevID.ToUpper
    Dim words As String() = DevID.Split(New Char() {","c})
    For Count = 0 To words.Length
        If DevID.Contains(words.ElementAt(Count)) = True Then
            MsgBox(DevID.Contains(words.ElementAt(Count)))
            MsgBox(words.ElementAt(Count))
            'RegKey.CreateSubKey("Intel_DEVID")
            'RegKey.SetValue("Intel_DEVID", "isLegacy")
            'RegKey.Close
            MsgBox("isLegacy")
        End If
    Next
```

DevConDump.txt contains a single line of text, containing some information that will tell me what it is (in this case, a set of Letters and Numbers, such as "DEV_0011", surrounded by useless information.

isLegacy.txt contains a List of Values that is possible for it to contain.

When I run this code, even if the value that it is checking is blatantly wrong (for example, if I put the string PETER in) it always returns true, that the value does not exist.

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

VB.NET, VS2010

Comment: I can't see any `Return True` here

Comment: What are you returning?

Comment: In this case, if it returns true, it will write "isLegacy" to the registry, and execute till finished. (This code has been commented out till I can solve this issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something DevID and words contain the same data:

```
 Dim words As String() = DevID.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

so

```
 DevID.Contains(words.ElementAt(Count)) = True
```

will always be true.

Did you intend:

```
DevCon.Contains(words.ElementAt(Count)) = True
```

Comment: Thanks! This was it! Will accept as Answer then it lets me in 3 Minutes! :)

(I can't believe I missed that...)

Comment: NP everyone needs a second pair of eyes sometimes